# How do I stop getting warning messages in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am getting the following warning message and I am okay with that warning.
"postgresql duplicate key violates unique constraint"

But I want to stop getting that warning message ? How do I do that ?

Comment: Sounds like an error, not a warning.  If you have a UNIQUE constraint on a table, you simply can't insert data that violates that.  That's the point of a UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: That's easy to fix: stop inserting values that are already present in the table.

Comment: ...or remove the constraint if you're fine with dupes.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I have a very big json file and I am parsing it and inserting it into a database. I need to collect all unique id's from it and maintain the id's in a table. I have put a constraint on the table, not to insert duplicate id's. Now, I know there are duplicate id's, and they wont be inserted into the table, but the query gives me warning. I don't want the warnings. What do I do ?

Comment: I mean to say I want to disable warnings in postgres.

Comment: @AnirudhKashyap - I don't think you can disable warnings.  You'll need to modify your `INSERT` statement to only insert if the data doesn't already exist.  I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Run the SQL:

```
SET client_min_messages = 'error';
```

or set it in `postgresql.conf` or via an `ALTER USER ... SET` or `ALTER DATABASE ... SET`, depending on the scope you want the setting to have.

You can do the same with `log_min_messages` if you want to suppress them in the server logs.